# Size of field from quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was reading "Extracting bits from coordinates of a point of an elliptic curve" (https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/324.pdf) and it claims that the field of order $p^2$ where $p$ is prime is equivalent to this quotient field: $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}\cong \mathbb{F}_{p}[x]/(x^2 - c)$ where $c$ is a non-quadratic residue (implying that $x^2-c$  is an irreducible polynomial). Wouldn't this imply that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\cong \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^2-2)$ since both $-1$ and $2$ are quadratic non-residues in $\mathbb{Z}_p$? This seemed strange to me since I thought $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^2-2)$ were different objects, but this would imply that they are isomorphic. Please let me know if this result is true. Also, is there a general result for the size of quotient rings? This may have already been asked, but I don't know enough math terminology to figure this out (I'm a computer science student).

Comment: $-1$ is a quadratic residue in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. $2$ is a quadratic residue in $\mathbb{Z}_7$. Did you have a specific $p$ in mind? But yes, two different choices for $c$ give isomorphic fields (or rings).

Comment: @aschepler Thanks, do you have a proof or source for why different choices for $c$ give isomorphic fields? It would be good to get some intuition. Also thanks for pointing out that $-1$ and $2$ CAN be quadratic residues for some $p$. I didn't think realize that $-1$ and $2$ might be quadratic residues in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ since they are quadratic non-residues in $\mathbb{Z}$. Is there a value of $p$ where both $-1$ and $2$ are quadratic non-residues? That might clarify my question.